# Why jQuery validation is not fired when addMethod is called within an object method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have this cute class:

**validations.js**

```
var Validation = function () {

    var load= function () {

        $.validator.addMethod("noweirdstuff", function (value, element) {
            return !(/\W/.test(value));}, "Username has invalid characters. Only letters, numbres & underscores allowed.");

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("noweirdstuff", function (options) {
            options.rules["noweirdstuff"] = true;
            if (options.message) { options.messages["noweirdstuff"] = options.message;}
        });   
    }

    return {
        init: function () {
            load();
        }
    };

}();
```

**validations.js** is bundled and minified with all javascript code into single file. Then, I'm using per page script to load only required code. In this case:

```
Validation.init();
```

But it doesn't seem fire the validation. I'm 100% sure that `Validation.init()` is being called.

It only works when I take it outside:

**validations.js**

```
 var Validation = function () {

        var load = function () {  
         // goodbye adding validation         
        }

        return {
            init: function () {
                load();
            }
        };

 }();

 $.validator.addMethod("noweirdstuff", function (value, element) {
                        return !(/\W/.test(value));}, "Username has invalid characters. Only letters, numbres & underscores allowed.");

 $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("noweirdstuff", function (options) {
                        options.rules["noweirdstuff"] = true;
                        if (options.message) { options.messages["noweirdstuff"] = options.message;}
                    });
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are registering your custom script validators after the page is loaded. The validation rules are applied to the whole document once unobtrusive validator loads, if your rules and validators haven't been added to the stack by then, they will be ignored.

I believe you could call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document)` after you have added your rules and validators, I'm not 100% sure this would work or if would apply validators twice.

**Edit:** Rephrased the answer

**Edit:** Added possible solution